How to Play Audio Through Earpiece on Both iOS and Android in Flutter
I am working on a Flutter project where I need to play audio through the earpiece (not the speaker) on both iOS and Android devices. Below is a sample of my current implementation:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:legalis/provider/communication/communication_provider.dart';
import 'package:legalis/provider/navigation/navigation_provider.dart';
import 'package:legalis/widgets/call/CallCountDown.dart';
import 'package:legalis/widgets/call_close_review_bottom_sheet.dart';

class CallPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CallPage({super.key, required this.callToken});

  final String? callToken;

  @override
  State<CallPage> createState() => _CallPageState();
}

class _CallPageState extends State<CallPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  final int levelClock = 28;
  late AudioPlayer _player;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Start the countdown timer when the widget is first displayed
    final communicationProvider =
        Provider.of<CommunicationProvider>(context, listen: false);
    communicationProvider.startTimer(Duration(seconds: 70));

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: levelClock),
    );

    _controller.forward();

    _player = AudioPlayer();

    _player.setAudioContext(
      AudioContext(
          android: AudioContextAndroid(isSpeakerphoneOn: false), // Set to false for earpiece
          iOS: AudioContextIOS(category: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final navigationProvider = Provider.of<NavigationProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000E2B),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 72,
                    height: 72,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4E03AQHWd3HiWA1I7g/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1693132754168?e=1723680000&v=beta&t=oyhL1JDIwlEP2yKtVEAvlQ-Z1k-EYM0A0whwep-TWXc',
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                      shape: const OvalBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 13),
                  const Text(
                    'Məhəmməd Məhəmmədov',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 13),
                  Countdown(
                    warning: (p0) {
                      if (p0) _player.play(AssetSource('voice/call_warning.mp3'));
                    },
                    onEnd: (bool isEnd) {
                      if (isEnd) {
                        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                          if (mounted) {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            navigationProvider.setNavVisible(false);
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF173786),
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  const CallCloseReviewBottomSheet(),
                            ).then(
                              (value) => navigationProvider.setNavVisible(true),
                            );
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    animation: StepTween(
                      begin: levelClock, // THIS IS A USER ENTERED NUMBER
                      end: 0,
                    ).animate(_controller),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 93,
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF333E55),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/volume-high.svg'),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/microphone-slash.svg'),
                  ),
                  Consumer<CommunicationProvider>(
                    builder: (context, provider, child) {
                      if (!provider.isConnected) {
                        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                          if (mounted) {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            navigationProvider.setNavVisible(false);
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF173786),
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  const CallCloseReviewBottomSheet(),
                            ).then(
                              (value) => navigationProvider.setNavVisible(true),
                            );
                          }
                        });
                      }
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          navigationProvider.setNavVisible(false);
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF173786),
                            builder: (context) =>
                                const CallCloseReviewBottomSheet(),
                          ).then(
                            (value) => navigationProvider.setNavVisible(true),
                          );
                        },
                        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/Frame 230.svg'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

have set the isSpeakerphoneOn property to false for Android and the category to AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord for iOS, but the audio still plays through the speaker. How can I ensure the audio plays through the earpiece on both platforms?
